Testing multiple pyspark pipelines with different environment variables loaded into a static file
Ok so I have a question-
For context: I am a new QA working in a team that uses pyspark as our ETL engine.
I use pytest as my testing framework.
We have multiple pipelines (ETL’S, I’m gonna use this term from now on) in the same repo.
of course, we use environment variables when running the pipeline (we inject them through airflow).
The problem being - the env variables are loaded into python variables, to a “RUN ENV” file, which is a global file for all pipelines.
Why is this a problem?
When I test the whole repo through CI, the first pipeline test that runs initializes the environment variables (through conftest.py), and they are in turn loaded into RUN ENV.
This causes an annoying situation When a pipeline finishes running,
and a new one begins: the RUN ENV has already been set up with the initial env variables I configured, and now it should be configured differently for the next pipeline!
I can go ahead and reconfigure each and every variable in RUN ENV (according to the current conftest being loaded) before every e2e test- but it seems wrong.
I know the use of RUN ENV is legitimate: usually only one pipeline is being invoked from a repo. But how can I work around this in a neat way in order to make everything clean and reasonable, so that RUN ENV could be reconfigured every other test? Or maybe defined differently so that this issue won’t matter?
I tried to decouple a lot of the code from the run env file even though I shouldn’t really touch pure source code
Tried to put env in fixtures rather than just into the conftest but it really doesn’t solve the problem as long as run env is loaded too soon

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Hello Yahli wellcome to StackOverflow. TL;DR create classes for diff. ETLs and modify the env. var. you need during lifecycle. Can you try to create a concrete class for different ETL?, if so, you can use the setUp() and tearDown() public methods that belongs to the TestCase class from pytest. In that way to can "set" / "unset" env. vars. on each concrete class that covers the ETL pipeline you need to test.

Hey, you’re totally right sadly that wouldn’t really work because the etls don’t directly use the env variables. I did figure out that if we return the env a from a function rather than a variable it could work out and be cleaner.I could do teardowns and setups, it feels cleaner, but I have my envs defined in conftest which feels correct, though it seems like you are in the right on this one. Just for sport: mind sharing something you did that worked out well for an etl? I

Writing it here if anyone else has a similar problem- me and the development team changed the “run env” file to not have consts- but have functions that return the env variables. –
